# Почему имена в шаблонах необязательны?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, language-lawyer

Смотрю [описание шаблонов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) и заметил, что имена параметров везде помечены как необязательные, но ведь если имя отсутствует, то параметр внутри функции я использовать не смогу. Получается, что я могу объявить и вызвать такую функцию (https://ideone.com/VVicO8):

```
template <int> void f() {}
```

Но все версии этой функции будут одинаковы между собой - тогда зачем мне вообще параметр шаблона? Есть ли реальная пользя от возможности не указывать имя и создавать нечто подобное? Зачем вообще эта возможность заложена в стандарт?

Comment: А если параметров несколько? Одно имя есть, другого нет? :)  А указывать, что вот тогда имя обязательно, а тогда - нет - вроде как-то неоправданно усложнять, нет?

Comment: @Harry, не понял. Если у какого-то параметра имени нет, то я не смогу его использовать, а значит реализация от параметра не зависит и его можно убрать. Или ты про специализацию шаблона говоришь?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/943155/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема неиспользуемых аргументов в шаблонах классов уже поднималась: [шаблонный класс, не использующий аргумент шаблона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/943155/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

В вашем конкретном примере - шаблон функции - использование фиктивного неименованного параметра может служить какой-то специальной внутренней более-менее экзотической технической цели.

Например, вам по какой-то причине необходимо иметь возможность генерировать копии одной и той же функции (т.е. делающие одно и то же), но при этом обладающие разной "адресной идентичностью", т.е. имеющие разные адреса

```
assert(&f<1> != &f<2>);
```

Comment: А разве ХОРОШИЙ оптимизатор не объединит f<1> и f<2> в одну функцию? Как говорится, инвариант жи есть. :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Язык требует того, чтобы адреса разных специализаций шаблонных функций были разными.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, уже был такой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618908/178988. По стандарту не должен, но вот фактически может. Вроде мы там так и не разобрались, это косяк компилятора или он успешно пользуется тем, что адреса никто не сравнивает.

Answer (score 4):

Не понимаю, почему вы решили, что все версии функции будут одинаковы. Отсутствие имени всего лишь означает, что параметр не используется, но это вовсе не значит, что `f<7>` это та же самая функция, что и `f<5>`, например. В частности можно сделать специализацию, которая будет делать что-то особенное, исходя из значения шаблонного аргумента:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int> 
void f() {}

template <> 
void f<7>() {
    std::cout << "seven\n";
}

int main()
{
  f<7>();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Немного перефразирую вопрос: Имеется ли смысл иметь в шаблоне параметр, который в этом шаблоне затем никак не используется? (Потому что опускать имя - это потеря семантики.)

Для этого есть масса сценариев:

1. Параметр просто используется для тегирования чтобы можно было получать разные классы просто используя разные специализации этого шаблона. Например [strong typedef](https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe/blob/master/include/type_safe/strong_typedef.hpp) `template <typename x_Tag, typename x_Type> class t_StrongTypedef` (`x_Tag` никак не используется, код от `x_Tag` не зависит, параметр задается пользователем)
2. Банальная специализация для разных параметров. Например SIMD вариант для параметров `int x_group_size` 2/4/8. (`x_group_size` никак не используется, но код от `x_group_size` зависит, параметр задается пользователем)
3. Использование как фиктивного параметра для SFINAE `typename x_Enabled = ::std::enable_if_t<` (`x_Enabled` никак не используется (и как раз часто опускается), код от `x_Enabled` не зависит, параметр может принимать только значение `void` и никогда не задается пользователем)
4. Использование как фиктивного параметра для класса чтобы можно было определять статические поля этого класса в заголовочном файле не вызывая ошибок линковки `typename x_Unused = void`. (`x_Unused` никак не используется, код от `x_Unused` не зависит, параметр может принимать только значение `void` и никогда не задается пользователем)